# SQL SPLIT with New Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have an MS Sql databse where I have following data:

```
ID   | ORD_No       | Date       | User       | Note       
-----+--------------+------------+------------+---------------
1    | 18/UT00120/ZS|            |            |---- Saved 10/10/2020 14:08 by John Snow, rest of the note 
                                               ----Saved on 11/11/2020 13:09 by Mike Kowalsky, rest of the   
                                                note ----  Saved on 12/11/2020 11:00 by Barbara Smith, rest of the note
```

From that I want to create following output:

```
ID   | ORD_No       | Date       | User           | Note       
-----+--------------+------------+----------------+---------------
1    | 18/UT00120/ZS| 10/10/2020 |  John Snow     | rest of the note
-----+--------------+------------+----------------+---------------
2    | 18/UT00120/ZS| 11/11/2020 |  Mike Kowalsky | rest of the note  
-----+--------------+------------+----------------+---------------
3    | 18/UT00120/ZS| 12/11/2020 |  Barbara Smith | rest of the note
```

Please adivce how can I achive required output.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there just one row you have shown in that first sample table, what splits up the notes? Or is each note a separate row? And which version of SQL Server?

Comment: each note is a separate row

Comment: if they are seperate row, cant you use `SUBSTRING()` to create diff columns?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server does not have very good string processing functionality.  You can do this but it is rather painful -- and not going to be flexible for all the variations on what notes might look like.

One big issue is that the built-in `string_split()` function does not take multi-character delimiters.  The following chooses a character that is not likely to be in the `notes`.

Also, the leading prefix is not consistent -- something there is an "on" and sometimes not.  So, this doesn't attempt to extract the "rest of the string".  It leaves in the prefix.  You could use additional string manipulations to handle this, but I suspect the real problem is more complex.

In any case, this comes quite close to what you want:

```
select t.id, t.ord_no, trim(s.value), s2.value as date
from t cross apply
     string_split(replace(note, '----', '~'), '~') s  cross apply
     (select top (1) s2.value
      from string_split(s.value, ' ') s2
      where try_convert(date, s2.value, 101) >= '2000-01-01'
     ) s2;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d463f5bbd43d3fcaac4359b6ee1bc086) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that the date inequality is used because `select try_convert(date, '')` returns `'1900-01-01'` rather than `NULL` as I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

I think, I have a solution for you. However, in different scenario it might not work. I have used `SUBSTRING`,`CHARINDEX`,`STRING_SPLIT`,`REPLACE` and `CAST` to achieve your desire answer. Here is my code given below=>

```
DECLARE @MyTable Table (ID INT, ORD_No VARCHAR(100),Note VARCHAR(300));
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES(1,'18/UT00120/ZS','Saved on 10/10/2020 14:08 by John Snow, rest of the note');
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES(2,'18/UT00120/ZS','Saved on 11/11/2020 07:08 by Mike Kowalsky, rest of the note');
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES(3,'18/UT00120/ZS','Saved on 12/11/2020 16:08 by Barbara Smith, rest of the note');
Select ID,ORD_No ,CAST(substring(Note,9,17) AS DATE) [Date],
       (SELECT top 1 value FROM STRING_SPLIT(SUBSTRING(Note,29,CHARINDEX(',',Note,0)),',')) AS [USER],
       RIGHT(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Note, CHARINDEX(',', Note), LEN(Note)), '', ''), len(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Note, CHARINDEX(',', Note), LEN(Note)), '', ''))-1) AS NOTE
FROM @MyTable
```

**Note:** This code will only work if your `Note` column data is always in same format as you gave in your question. Check also [db-fiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e525e65027fd02f736c6cf19fa9417a1).